# Manage gmail with Java. Filter inbox by "sent to"

Tags: java, email

This is my sample code to access to my inbox. It works, but I need filter the mails by addressee because I'm using alias for differents sites (mymail+alias1@gmail.com, mymail+alias2@gmail.com, mymail+alias3@gmail.com,...).

And there aren't a message.getDeliveredTo() or similar. Any idea? Another library? I'm using java mail api.

```
String host = "pop.gmail.com";
String username = "mymail@gmail.com";
String password = "password";

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");

Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties);

Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
store.connect(host, username, password);

Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();

for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  MimeMessage message = (MimeMessage) messages[i];
  System.out.println("---------------------------------");
  System.out.println(message.getSender());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `Address[] getRecipients()` method of class `Message`. Every address has its receipment type (TO, CC, BCC). Please refer to Java Mail API: https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Message.html#getRecipients-javax.mail.Message.RecipientType-